# CakePHP How to limit the fields of both tables in a hasMany query?

Tags: php, cakephp, orm

I have two tables in my database:

**processo_administrativo** hasMany **documento_processo_administrativo**

And I would like to retrive all records but (for performance reasons) limiting the fields (columns) using select():

So I tried:

```
<?php

$tablePA = TableRegistry::get('ProcessoAdministrativo');
    
debug($tablePA->find()
        ->select('codigo_pa')
        ->contain(['DocumentoProcessoAdministrativo' => 
           fn($q) => $q->select(['id','descricao','ordem','processo_administrativo_id'])
        ])->toArray());
```

But the result was **all ProcessoAdministrativo without DocumentoProcessoAdministrativo**
Example:

```
[
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\ProcessoAdministrativo) {
        'codigo_pa' => 'PGE/001.000091/2021',
        'documento_processo_administrativo' => []
    }
]
```

My another attempt was using enableAutoFields(true) and the result was "almost there":

```
<?php

$tablePA = TableRegistry::get('ProcessoAdministrativo');

debug($tablePA->find()
        ->select('codigo_pa')
        ->contain(['DocumentoProcessoAdministrativo' => 
           fn($q) => $q->select(['id','descricao','ordem','processo_administrativo_id'])
        ])->toArray());
```

This time, I got the hasMany records (and only with the fields that I defined) but, unfortunately, all fields from ProcessoAdministrativo were retrieved too (**but I just want one field: codigo_pa**):

```
[
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\ProcessoAdministrativo) {
        'codigo_pa' => 'PGE/001.000091/2021',
        'id' => (int) 91877,
        'exito_sucumbencia_id' => null,
        'especializada_id' => (int) 97,
        'classificacao_id' => null,
        'materia_id' => null,
        //...and much more fields here :(
        'documento_processo_administrativo' => [
            (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\DocumentoProcessoAdministrativo) {
                'id' => (int) 120709,
                'descricao' => 'Termo de Abertura',
                'ordem' => (int) 0,
                'processo_administrativo_id' => (int) 91877,
            }
   //...
```

So, How Can I limit the fields of both tables using CakePHP find() ?

Comment: try: `$tablePA->find()->select(['ProcessoAdministrativo.codigo_pa', 'DocumentoProcessoAdministrativo.id', 'DocumentoProcessoAdministrativo.descricao', descricao, //* ... etc */])`

Comment: @Salines : SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "DocumentoProcessoAdministrativo.id" could not be bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging `hasMany`/`belongsToMany` records (which are being obtained in separate queries) into the results happens on PHP level, therefore you must select the primary key of `ProcessoAdministrativo`, eg the other side of your foreign key constraint, otherwise the ORM cannot stitch the results together, as it cannot tell which `DocumentoProcessoAdministrativo` record belongs to wich `ProcessoAdministrativo` record, as there would be no data that it could match against the `processo_administrativo_id` foreign key.

```php
$query = $tablePA
    ->find()
    ->select(['id', 'codigo_pa'])
    ->contain([
        'DocumentoProcessoAdministrativo' => fn($q) => 
            $q->select(['id', 'descricao', 'ordem', 'processo_administrativo_id'])
    ]);
```

If you don't want the `ProcessoAdministrativo.id` field in the results, then you need to filter it out after the records have been queried, for example using a result formatter:

```php
$query = $tablePA
    ->find()
    // ...
    ->formatResults(function (\Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface $results) {
        return $results->map(function ($row) {
            unset($row['id']);

            return $row;
        });
    });
```

Comment: would be nice to see this explanation on cake book someday, thanks !